# OpenGL camera rotation using gluLookAt

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I am trying to use gluLookAt to implement an FPS style camera in OpenGL fixed function pipeline. The mouse should rotate the camera in any given direction.

I store the position of the camera:

```
float xP;
float yP;
float zP;
```

I store the look at coordinates:

```
float xL;
float yL;
float zL;
```

The up vector is always set to `(0,1,0)`

I use this camera as follows: `gluLookAt(xP,yP,zP, xL,yL,zL, 0,1,0);`

I want my camera to be able to be able to move along the yaw and pitch, but not roll.

After every frame, I reset the coordinates of the mouse to the middle of the screen. From this I am able to get a change in both x and y.

How can I convert the change in x and y after each frame to appropriately change the lookat coordinates (xL, yL, zL) to rotate the camera?

Comment: The look at, up and your right/left vectors should be perpendicular to each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a set of vectors:

```
fwd = (0, 0, -1);
rht = (1, 0, 0);
up = (0, 1, 0);
```

Given that Your `x` and `y`, taken from the mouse positions You mentioned, are small enough You can take them directly as yaw and pitch rotations respectively. With yaw value rotate the `rht` and `fwd` vectors over the `up` vector, than rotate `fwd` vactor over the `rht` with pitch value. This way You'll have a new forward direction for Your camera (`fwd` vactor) from which You can derive a new look-at point (`L = P + fwd` in Your case).

You have to remember to restrict pitch rotation not to have `fwd` and `up` vectors parallel at some point. You can prevent that by recreating the `up` vector every time You do pitch rotation - simply do a cross product between `rht` and `fwd` vactors. A side-note here though - this way `up` will not always be (0,1,0).